# How to add another parameter to formdata in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am sending a file object to my server from angularJS like this -

```
var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        deferred.reject('some error occurred');
                });
```

This is my Asp.Net MVC controller -

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

I want to send one more parameter (say userId) with the same request. Is it possible to do so? How should I recieve it at the server end. I tried adding `fd.append('userId', userId)` to the formdata object, but it didn't work. Please tell how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**: When I do bind like I mention, I get below error:

`Can't bind multiple parameters ('file' and 'userId') to the request'scontent.`

**Edit2**: I also tried creating an object like so -

```
public class PostedInfo{
    public HttpPostedFileBase file {get;set;}
    public string userId {get;set;}        
}
```

and changed post method to -

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]PostedInfo fd)
```

But, now this error is thrown, which is quite obvious as the request is json -

```
The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.
```

Not sure how to tell tell that fd.file is a `multipart/form-data` entity.

Comment: You should be able to include additional form data in js as you did. Did you use `[FromBody]string userId` in `Post` method parameter for userId on the server? If you add a breakpoint or inspect the raw request itself, your extra parameter should simply appear as a POST parameter to the request.

Comment: Yeah, I added the params in asp.net too but it throws this error - Can't bind multiple parameters ('file' and 'userId') to the request's content.

Comment: Please see Edit1 and Edit2

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. The issue is that HttpPostedFileBase seems to not work quite well with webapi, so instead one should use `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` for this. Code below -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            // get the additional parameter
            var userId = provider.FormData.GetValues("userId").FirstOrDefault();

            string filepath = provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName;

            return <your_custom_response_here>;
    }
```

Here, you can see, I also got the userId in the server code apart from uploading the file.

Well, `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` will save the file with a cryptic name (BodyPart_...). You can get rid of that by building your own CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider. Found an awesome [link](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/) as to how to format the file name while saving. Worth a read.